# Plugin or anything for editing data in table cell in mobile?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html

See i have a table in mobile and i want its data to be editable. Currently, I am using textbox to make those editable but it doesn't look pretty good(values are cut off especially if the values are larger).

I am thinking of something like when you tap on the cell it will pop-up a modal and a textbox to edit that cell? is there something of a plugin that looks like that or probably if you have a better solution would you mind sharing it? thanks
[image]

Answer (score 1):

[DataTables JS](https://datatables.net/) is the best bet to use, this allows cells ot be editable. Here is an [example](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple) given.

If you want to enable editing on tap. I suggest you to use [JQuery Touch Punch](http://touchpunch.furf.com/). It will translate your click to tap event.

Answer (score 1):

I have been using [ng-table](http://ng-table.com/#/editing/demo-inline/) and [DataTables](https://editor.datatables.net/examples/inline-editing/simple). 
Based on your ease, you can use anyone of them

Answer (score 0):

```
you can use angular bootstarp modal 

Just open a modal on click of any cell and set the value of that cell in the modalInstance.result.then() function.
below is sample code for opening a modal.

You can find more detail about modal on below link
https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/



var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
      animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
      ariaLabelledBy: 'modal-title',
      ariaDescribedBy: 'modal-body',
      templateUrl: 'myModalContent.html',
      controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
      controllerAs: '$ctrl',
      size: size,
      appendTo: parentElem,
      resolve: {
        items: function () {
          return $ctrl.items;
        }
      }
    });

    modalInstance.result.then(function (returned_value) {

    // Set the value of selected cell here

    }, function () {
      $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
    });
```